# Sorting text based on following sibling - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Is it possible sorting text based on following sibling when it comes same attribute value and not sort text if it's comes `start-with text Generally`. Text start only single word and start Word and Digit Example `S corporation, Co-sale, five504, seven7(a).` In this XML Three types of Attribute value
**Input File**

```
    <document>
    <p specific-use="Main">Accounts and Accounting</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Regulation A offerings, accounting fees for, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">19.9</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">S corporation, accounting closing provision in buy-sell agreement, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">3.53&#x0192;</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Sarbanes-Oxley Act of 2002, public accounting firms' required registration with Public Company Accounting Oversight Board (PCAOB) under, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">17.5</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">18.9</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">20.13</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Stock dividends <emphasis type="roman">versus</emphasis> stock splits, accounting treatment of, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">18.30</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Main">Agreements</p>
    <p specific-use="seeAlso"><emphasis type="roman">See also</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Contracts</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Buy-sell agreements. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Buy-Sell Agreement</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Co-sale agreement. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Right of First Refusal and Co-Sale Agreement</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Confidentiality agreements. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Confidentiality</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Founders, agreements between. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Founder of New Business Entity</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Investment agreement. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Investment Agreement</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Main">CAN-SPAM Act</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">13.24</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Main">Capital</p>
    <p specific-use="seeAlso"><emphasis type="roman">See also</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Venture Capital</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.1</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Attorney's role in obtaining capital</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.1</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Appropriate sources of capital, identification of, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.6</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Business plan, preparation of, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.5</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Small Business Administration (SBA)</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">five504 loan program, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11C</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">seven7(a) loan program, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11B</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Direct loans by SBA, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.12</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Guaranty of loan by SBA, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.13</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Maximum maturity for loan, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11B</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Specialized SBA loan programs, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11E</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Sources of capital</p>
    <p specific-use="Main">Buy-Sell Agreement</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">3.13</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">4.28</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Redemption format, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">3.19</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">S corporations. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">S Corporations</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Shareholder buy-sell agreement</p>
</document>
```

**Expected Output**

```
    <document>
    <p specific-use="Main">Accounts and Accounting</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Regulation A offerings, accounting fees for, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">19.9</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Sarbanes-Oxley Act of 2002, public accounting firms' required registration with Public Company Accounting Oversight Board (PCAOB) under, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">17.5</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">18.9</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">20.13</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">S corporation, accounting closing provision in buy-sell agreement, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">3.53&#x0192;</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Stock dividends <emphasis type="roman">versus</emphasis> stock splits, accounting treatment of, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">18.30</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Main">Agreements</p>
    <p specific-use="seeAlso"><emphasis type="roman">See also</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Contracts</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Buy-sell agreements. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Buy-Sell Agreement</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Confidentiality agreements. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Confidentiality</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Co-sale agreement. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Right of First Refusal and Co-Sale Agreement</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Founders, agreements between. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Founder of New Business Entity</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Investment agreement. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Investment Agreement</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Main">CAN-SPAM Act</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">13.24</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Main">Capital</p>
    <p specific-use="seeAlso"><emphasis type="roman">See also</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">Venture Capital</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.1</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Attorney's role in obtaining capital</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.1</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Appropriate sources of capital, identification of, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.6</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Business plan, preparation of, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.5</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Small Business Administration (SBA)</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Direct loans by SBA, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.12</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">five504 loan program, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11C</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Guaranty of loan by SBA, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.13</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Maximum maturity for loan, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11B</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">seven7(a) loan program, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11B</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub2">Specialized SBA loan programs, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">1.11E</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Sources of capital</p>
    <p specific-use="Main">Buy-Sell Agreement</p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Generally, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">3.13</xref>, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">4.28</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Redemption format, <xref ref-type="other" rid="none">3.19</xref></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">S corporations. <emphasis type="roman">See</emphasis> <emphasis type="bold">S Corporations</emphasis></p>
    <p specific-use="Sub1">Shareholder buy-sell agreement</p>
</document>
```

Not sure, How to sort text based on condition?
 Sorting Text only start single word and start Word and Digit Example `S corporation, Co-sale, five504, seven7(a).`
**Marked Image**
[image]

Comment: So far I have not understood what you want to achieve. Consider simplifying the samples and/or to write a longer, more precise description as to which elements you want to sort under which conditions. For instance, if you want to sort `p` elements having the same `specific-use` attribute value, then certainly `for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="@specific-use"` can help identifying and if needed, sorting them, but I am guessing as to what you might be looking for.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Thanks for the reply my question. Actually this document is already sorted but some cases not comes in alphabetical ordered. How to sorting some cases in alphabetical ordered when start text Examples `S corporation, Co-sale, five504, seven7(a).`?

Comment: It is still not clear to me and not recognizable in the complex sample which elements are to be sorted and which not. If you want to sort p elements that start with `'S corporation', 'Co-sale', 'five504', 'seven7'`, are they to be sorted in relation to only the other elements starting with the key terms or in relation to all elements? It would help if you simplify the samples and mark/show us exactly which elements are to be sorted and to which positions.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, I have edited my question an upload a marked Image. How to move only Highlighted point? Thanks Sandy!

Comment: Is the case (i.e. upper or lower case) of letters ignored when sorting? Which order puts `S corporation` with the space after the `S` between `Sarbanes-Oxley` and `Stock`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Yes, We can ignore the case of letter. Yes, we can put with space after the `S` between `Sarbanes-Oxley` and `Stock`.

Comment: Well, using lower-case or case-independent sorting is easily possible in XSLT 2 but I don;t know which collation sorts spaces between `a` and `t`.

Comment: Sir, I don't understand collation sorts spaces between `a` and `t`. Can you explain one particular line?

Comment: If using `xsl:sort` or other sorting options in XSLT, then, like done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepK, it is possible to use the `lower-case` function to ignore the case of letters, that is also possible using a collation I think. But I don't know of a sorting algorithm that sorts `S corporation` between `Sarbanes` and `Stock`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, I have see your output two points moving good  `five504` and `seven7` but how to move this point `S corporation` and `Co-sale`? Please Help me if it's possible.

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to tell you that I don't see any obvious sort order or algorithm that sorts `S corporation` between `Sarbanes` and `Stock`. And the dash in `Co-sale` is also something that Unicode based sorting will not position after `Confidentiatity`. XSLT processors might be able to use a language or culture specific sorting called collation but you need to explain which language/culture based algorithm that is supposed to be. Do you want to ignore spaces or punctuations like `-`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Thanks for your valuable time :)

Comment: Sir, If I want to ignore spaces or punctuation like `-` then Can we generate Expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments you want to sort ignoring case and ignoring symbols like spaces or punctuations; in XSLT (3 at least, probably also in XSLT 2, support in general of such features might depend on the processor) you can use a collation with that arguments e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="sort-if" as="xs:string*" select="'S corporation', 'Co-sale', 'five504', 'seven7'"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes" suppress-indentation="p"/>

  <xsl:template match="document">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="p" composite="yes" group-adjacent="@specific-use, not(starts-with(., 'Generally'))">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()[2]">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                          <xsl:sort select="." collation="http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?lang=en;ignore-case=yes;ignore-symbols=yes"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
                      </xsl:apply-templates>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepK/2 seems to have the right order using Saxon 9.8 HE, test whether you can use that in your environment or whether your processor supports the used collation arguments.

Comment: Sir, You are Great and Thanks for Solving my problem :)